# Why fdump-class-hierarchy gives two pointers int vtable for virtual functions

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast, vtable, typeid, virtual-destructor

for the following class,

```
class A
{
public:

    char VarA;
    int VarB;

    virtual ~A(){}
};
```

g++ fdump-class-hierarchy gives me for the Vtable,

```
Vtable for A
A::_ZTV1A: 4u entries
0     (int (*)(...))0
8     (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI1A)
16    (int (*)(...))A::~A
24    (int (*)(...))A::~A
```

but I don't understand:
1. What are the two first pointers?
2. Why are 2 pointers for the virtual destructor?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe of interest: http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/cxxabi-1.83.html#vtable. In particular "offset to top", "RTTI", "destructor pair".

Answer (score 0):

Let's try with the following demo code:

```
class A
{
public:

    char VarA;
    int VarB;

    virtual ~A();
};

#include <cstdio>

A::~A() { 
    std::printf("A::~A()\n");
}

#include <typeinfo>

void *complete_object_addr(A &ref) {
    return dynamic_cast<void*> (&ref);
}

const std::type_info& get_typeinfo(A &ref) {
    return typeid(ref);
}

void explicit_destructor_call(A *p) {
    p->~A();
}

void delete_object(A *p) {
    delete p;
}

#include <memory>

void create_object (A *p) {
    new (p) A;
}
```

in [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/hEfHQW).

### The vtable

Let's start with the constructor invocation

```
void create_object (A *p) {
    new (p) A;
}
```

to see where is the vptr and the vtable:

```
create_object(A*):
        movq    $vtable for A+16, (%rdi)
        ret
```

The `A*` parameter is in `rdi`, the vptr is at offset 0 in the object so `*(void*)p` gives the vptr. The vtable is generated as:

```
vtable for A:
        .quad   0
        .quad   typeinfo for A
        .quad   A::~A() [complete object destructor]
        .quad   A::~A() [deleting destructor]
```

We see that the vptr points inside (not at the beginning of the vtable): `.quad` means 8 bytes to the vptr points to the third element: `A::~A() [complete object destructor]`.

This way of outputting the vtable is much clearer than the one in your question: there are two destructors that can be called virtually:

- "[complete object destructor]" to destroy a complete object,
- "[deleting destructor]" to delete a complete object.

### The virtual destructors

Indeed, the code for `explicit_destructor_call(A*)` defined as

```
void explicit_destructor_call(A *p) {
    p->~A();
}
```

shows a call to the function pointer `vptr[0]`.

```
explicit_destructor_call(A*):
        movq    (%rdi), %rax
        jmp     *(%rax)
```

The call to the virtual function is `(p->vptr)(p)`; note that *passing the `this` argument is implicit in the generated code as it's in a register*.

There is a trick here and you will need to turn the assembly directives filter OFF to see it:

```
.text
.size   A::~A() [base object destructor], .-A::~A() [base object destructor]
.globl  A::~A() [complete object destructor]
.set    A::~A() [complete object destructor],A::~A() [base object destructor]
```

I'm not used to these directives but it certainly means that `A::~A() [complete object destructor]` is actually `A::~A() [base object destructor]` which is:

```
.LC0:
        .string "A::~A()"
A::~A() [base object destructor]:
        movq    $vtable for A+16, (%rdi)
        movl    $.LC0, %edi
        jmp     puts
```

- first the vptr is set as in the constructor: the dynamic type of `*this` is reset of `A`, which is only useful for the destruction of base class subobjects, not of complete objects,
- then `puts("A::~A()");` is called (which shows that the `printf` specification string is interpreted at compile time when possible).

The function `delete_object(A*)` defined as

```
void delete_object(A *p) {
    delete p;
}
```

is compiled as

```
delete_object(A*):
        testq   %rdi, %rdi
        je      .L8
        movq    (%rdi), %rax
        jmp     *8(%rax)
```

This one is slightly more complicated: a test of `p!=0` is needed as `delete p;` is legal when `p` is null. If `p` is non zero, the code jumps to `(char*)vptr + 8` which is the next item in the vtable: `vptr[1]`.

That destructor is compiled as:

```
A::~A() [deleting destructor]:
        pushq   %rbx
        movq    %rdi, %rbx
        movq    $vtable for A+16, (%rdi)
        movl    $.LC0, %edi
        call    puts
        movq    %rbx, %rdi
        movl    $16, %esi
        popq    %rbx
        jmp     operator delete(void*, unsigned long)
```

First we reset the dynamic type to `A`. (I don't think this is ever actually needed.) Then we output the text as in the "just destroy the object" destructor, then we call `operator delete(this,sizeof(A));`.

### RTTI: `typeid`, `dynamic_cast`

Obtaining the value of `typeid(lvalue of A)` is very simple;

```
const std::type_info& get_typeinfo(A &ref) {
    return typeid(ref);
}
```

is compiled as

```
get_typeinfo(A&):
        movq    (%rdi), %rax
        movq    -8(%rax), %rax
        ret
```

We see that `vptr[-1]` is read and returned.

And finally, obtaining the address of a most derived object by `dynamic_cast<void*>`

```
void *complete_object_addr(A &ref) {
    return dynamic_cast<void*> (&ref);
}
```

is extremely simple:

```
complete_object_addr(A&):
        movq    (%rdi), %rax
        addq    -16(%rax), %rdi
        movq    %rdi, %rax
        ret
```

The most derived object that at offset `vptr[-2]` after `this` (these offsets are almost always negative).